# How to Implement Micro Frontend in Angular (Alternative to Iframe)

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-elements, micro-frontend

we are trying to implement micro-frontend concept in Angular,
where we have 2 angular applications App1 and App2 both separate project running individually on their own server.
we want to integrate App2 inside a component of App1 on button click event, we have currently implemented this with Iframe but we want to implement this
in a micro-fronted approach.

any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your service has network balancer o similar type microservices ?

Comment: @Soleil they are standalone projects developed by different teams but I have a requirement to include App2 into some component of App1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use webpack5 module federation for implementing that because it will be part of upcoming angular releases as well. For how to use refer to :- https://www.angulararchitects.io/aktuelles/the-microfrontend-revolution-part-2-module-federation-with-angular/

Comment: Could you please provide more information or a source for "module federation will be part of upcoming Angular releases"? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Angular Elements is also a good way of doing micro frontends.
See https://medium.com/swlh/build-micro-frontends-using-angular-elements-the-beginners-guide-75ffeae61b58